# Keychain Sharing/Failed to create provisioning profile - xcode

Tags: xcode, firebase

estou com essa mensagem de erro quando tento criar o provisioning profile :
Failed to create provisioning profile.

There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

No profiles for 'FirebaseConfiguracao' were found

Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'FirebaseConfiguracao'.
Tem que ter conta paga para usar isso?
Eu já coloquei a minha conta e parece que está certo... segue o link com uns screenshots que eu tirei para ajudar na resolução.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8spxuDTZ3I8QlBLOE56Q1ZwZms

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para realizar a conexão com o Firebase não é necessário incluir uma Keychain sharing. Tenta retirar essa configuração.

Comment: Deu certo, Obrigado.